# How to implement Linq on DataTable

Tags: .net, linq, ado.net

I have a result set in the form of DataTable. 
The data table has 2 fields named `startTime` and `endTime`.
I need to get the row with max difference in the `startTime` and `endTime` fields.

I think this can be easily implemented using Linq but don't know how to do the same on data table.

Comment: Is the `DataTable` associated to a `DataSet` and, if so, is that `DataSet` strongly typed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Linq To DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx) is what you are looking for.

If you call AsEnumerable() on your datatable you can write a normal Linq query to it.

Comment: But here i want to perform Max operation on the difference of start time and the end time. Do this is possible through Linq

Answer (score 2):

You could sort the rows in the [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) by the difference between the `EndTime` and `StartTime` fields and select the first row from the top.

In this example I'm using the [DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx) method to get a sequence of [DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx) objects out of the specified [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx):

```
var rowWithLongestTimespan = (from row in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                              let endTime = row.Field<DateTime>("EndTime")
                              let startTime = row.Field<DateTime>("StartTime") 
                              orderby endTime - startTime descending
                              select row).First();
```

Comment: I would not use orderby here. Sort is O(n*log(n)) max is O(n).

Comment: @achitaka-san True. IMHO this is just a simpler solution than some alternatives, such as grouping the rows by the difference between `endTime` and `startTime` and then selecting the row where the difference is equal to the group with the highest value. But as you say, it might cause a performance issue, depending on the number of rows involved in the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
        var maxDiff = dataTable
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(row => row.Field<DateTime>("endDate") - row.Field<DateTime>("startDate"))
            .Max();

        var allHavingMaxDiff = dataTable
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Where(row => row.Field<DateTime>("endDate") - row.Field<DateTime>("startDate") == maxDiff);

        var oneHavingMaxDiff = allHavingMaxDiff.First();
```